# Configuring calendar markers in emacs

Tags: emacs, calendar, elisp

I'm very new to emacs.

I want to start using emacs' calendar and diary functionality.

The code below successfully highlights days with a diary entry using "D".

I would like the current day to be highlighted with "T".

```
;;; calendar
(require 'calendar)

(setq mark-diary-entries-in-calendar t)
(setq diary-entry-marker "D")

(add-hook 'today-visible-calendar-hook 'calendar-mark-today)
(setq calendar-today-marker "T")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Aren't you able to see the "T" marker? Did you try reloading Calendar?

For that purpose I created a simple function and bound to something useful for me:

```
(defun reload-calendar ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer-and-window)
  (calendar))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-0") (lambda () (interactive) (reload-calendar)))
```

Comment: Indeed, I have returned this morning and all is well... No idea. Certainly did close and reopen Emacs a number of times.

Answer (score 2):

For my Emacs (version 26.0.50.2) the name of the hook has changed, it is now `calendar-today-visible-hook`, so the following works for me:

```
(add-hook 'calendar-today-visible-hook 'calendar-mark-today)
```

Thought it was worth mentioning, in case anyone else finds themselves here and the accepted answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The above code should work atleast it worked for me, maybe you did not restart calendar after evaluating the code above. Also in case you do not know, you can also highlight current day by giving it a different face. For example the following code will highlight current day with red background

```
(add-hook 'today-visible-calendar-hook 'calendar-mark-today)
(custom-theme-set-faces 'user '(calendar-today ((t :background "red"))))
```